# How to configure "App Domain" (needed for Open Graph action) for a pure native iOS app (no web app)?

Tags: ios, facebook-opengraph

My iOS app would like to publish an open graph action when user uploaded a photo to my (web) server from the app(e.g. User **uploaded** a **photo** to Server). The app will be the only point that I'll interact with Facebook, and I do not maintain a web or mobile web that wanted to use Facebook login.

Whenever I try to publish the said action+object (a URL of the page in my server), Facebook will complain invalid domain and suggest I configure the 'App Domain'.

However, in Facebook app settings, in order to configure the 'App Domain' I need to have either a Web (that users Facebook login) or Mobile Web or Facebook tab. Which I do not plan to support. If I just go ahead and set an 'App Domain' Facebook will not allow me to save.

Did I miss something? Or my use case is not the one meant by Open Graph?

Answer (score 2):

If your domain is example.com, just enable "Website with Facebook Login" in the App Dashboard (even though you will not have a web integration) and for the site url enter: http://example.com
Then enter example.com in "App Domains".

Comment: Yup, that allowed me to use the App Domain, but, wouldn't that require me to submit some screenshots of my web site (that presumably needs to use the Facebook login) when I submits the Open Graph terms for approval?

Comment: Was just wondering if this is an accepted/common practice to simply set the domain you need as Webiste with Facebook Login, where in reality you will not have such web site? Or there's any other "proper" way of doing it?

Comment: I agree, it seems like a bit of a hack. Is this really how they expect us to set up open graph? They don't anticipate needing a solution for a standalon iPhone App?

Comment: "Website with Facebook Login" in the App Dashboard doesn’t exist in the new Facebook developer layout! How does one fix it today? Can't be only me that wants a pure, native iOS app.